# How to persist data with Spark/ Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm performing a batch process using Spark with Scala.
Each day, I need to import a sales file into a Spark dataframe and perform some transformations. ( a file with the same schema, only the date and the sales values may change) 
At the end of the week, I need to use all daily transformations to perform weekly aggregations. Consequently, I need to persist the daily transformations so that I don't let Spark do everything at the end of the week. ( I want to avoid importing all data and performing all transformations at the end of the week).
I would like also to have a solution that supports incremental updates ( upserts).
 I went through some options like Dataframe.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY). I would like to know if there are better options like maybe using Hive tables ?
What are your suggestions on that ? 
What are the advantages of using Hive tables over Dataframe.persist ? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can save results of your daily transformations in a parquet (or orc) format, partitioned by day. Then you can run your weekly process on this parquet file with a query that filters only the data for last week. Predicate pushdown and partitioning works pretty efficiently in Spark to load only the data selected by the filter for further processing.

```
  dataframe 
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .partitionBy("day") // assuming you have a day column in your DF
    .parquet(parquetFilePath)
```

SaveMode.Append option allows you to incrementally add data to parquet files (vs overwriting it using SaveMode.Overwrite)

Comment: Back to you Denis. I got the expected results when it comes to upserts so thank you !

Comment: Be careful though, it is very easy to insert duplicated rows into parquet files! Make sure you thought through your error recovery strategy. Unlike databases, there are no built-in checks for it. In particular there is no notion of primary key

Comment: Well yeah that's the problem, I need to handle upserts when not only I need to append new records but overwrite records with same key. So I guess I'll be needing a database layer

Comment: If updates happen not too often and the amount of daily data is not too large, it may be easier (vs introducing a DB) to re-read the original daily data, join it  with updates while replacing the old values with updated ones for selected rows and then save results as a new parquet file to be used instead of the original one. The benefit of this is that the old version is preserved and it is easy to do roll-back if needed.